# Displaying a .txt file as pure text without editing the file contents

Tags: html, text, pre, php-include

I have a .txt file containing code that I cannot change the contents of. And I need to display it in two ways.

One way is inside a div as selectable, copy-able type (currently done with: 

`<pre><?php include '/file_location.txt';?></pre>` ).

The other way is as a direct link to the .txt file so such link can have it's address copied and emailed to someone, saved as..., or any other function one might like a direct link for. (So just like `<a href="/file_location.txt">` basically.)

The issue is that when php including the text file into a div any <%> strings interfere with the original source text. I need to preserve the integrity of the original .txt files (so I can't go changing all the left carrots into `&lt;`).

**So is there a good way to display the contents of the text file without issues with `< >` and still maintain it's original integrity for sake of direct-linking?**

*EDIT:* 
I currently have two separate files performing this function, one with html encodings and the raw unedited .txt file. I'd really like to get these two displays working with just one file so that each new bit of source code doesn't need to be converted to an html-friendly version and adding just its .txt file will grant both view options.

*EDIT 2:* 
Using `<textarea>` instead of `<pre>` will not interfere with the `<` characters and i could CSS it to look how I want, but I don't like the idea of the user being able to resize it themselves.

Comment: stuff it into an iframe with text/plain content-type?

Comment: @MarcB I'm not sure what the iframe would bring that I couldn't implement in the existing frame. Also as a dirty little secret, this section actually already exists in an iframe.

Comment: you came nest iframes, and by putting this text into the iframe, you can prevent the browser from doing any interpretation/rendering. otherwise you're stuck with things like `htmlspecialchars()`. things will APPEAR as `<>`, but within the page source will be `&lt;&gt;`.

Comment: Do yu want to get rid off all HTML tags??

Comment: @BarışKURT The source code in the .txt files sometimes use `< >` for the language that they are in, but I do not want them to be construed as html tags - since they aren't. So I want it to show all the `< >` but as plain text, not HTML tags.

Comment: ok. I answered the question: highlight_file i gave an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("file.txt")) ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php include '/file_location.txt';?>
```

to display special HTML characters from a text file.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this for my php files. I think it will be usefull for you too.

```
   <?php
highlight_file("test.php");
?>
```

edit: I tried on a html file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add `<pre></pre>` at the beginning/end of your `.txt`. I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but I think this will not interfere with the `<>` tags.

Comment: Basically, I have a .txt file of source code that I can't change the contents of. Right now that means I have to link to this raw file, then create another file that uses html encoding (basically changing all `<` to `&lt;`).

I would like to not have to make this extra file, and somehow include the contents of the .txt file in a div without worrying about `<` characters.

I don't think putting the `<pre></pre>` inside the .txt file would do anything differently than outside, but regardless I can't edit the .txt file itself.